# WPF: How can I get the height of a listview row

Tags: wpf, listview

I need to know how high (in pixels) a row in a listview control will be. The row just contains text, nothing fancy

Answer (score 3):

i think you will find your answer here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/446cd40b-ec43-4e9f-a2cc-ee6932fd09a9/